# How to prevent user from entering text into a form field using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to prevent the user from entering more than 100 characters into a textarea. I already wrote the code that will detect when the user's post reaches 100 characters. But I have no idea how to prevent him from typing any more beyond that point:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.comment').keyup(function(){
       var count = this.value.length;
       if (count > 100) {

           // what goes here???

       }           
   });

});


  <textarea class="comment" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
```

Comment: you should have server side validation of this too, obviously :D

Comment: what if you hold down a keyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `keypress` may be nicer. You could just `return false;`

```
​$('textarea').keypress(function() {
    if(this.value.length >= 100) 
        return false;
})​​​​​;​
```

This also prevents the user from holding down a key to enter several characters beyond the limit.

If you want to use `keyup`, you could do this:

```
$('.comment').keyup(function(){
   var count = this.value.length;
   if (count > 100) {

    this.value = this.value.substr(0,100);

   }           
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
​jQuery('textarea').keypress(function(e) {
    if(this.value.length >= 100) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
})​​​​​;​
```

preventDefault is needed for some browsers like IE and supported by all; 
but really needed only for a href onclick

keyup is not the good event to prevent keys... key repeat is made with keydown

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea[maxlength]').keyup(function(){
        var max = parseInt($(this).attr(’maxlength’));
        if($(this).val().length > max){
            $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, $(this).attr('maxlength')));
        }

        $(this).parent().find('.charsRemaining').html('You have ' + (max - $(this).val().length) + ' characters remaining');
    });
});
```

From http://that-matt.com/2008/07/textarea-maxlength-with-jquery/

There is also a plugin for this http://remysharp.com/2008/06/30/maxlength-plugin/